# Jquery Not working after Re-writing using .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I have tried to use .htaccess but my rewriting work fine but note ajax codes there just froze not doing any thin is this because rewriting?

**MY .Htaccess Code**

```
#Turn Rewriter on
RewriteEngine on



RewriteRule ^testthis test/test.php [Nc,L]
```

**My Php Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>THaalinda</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>

Testing 


<script src='testthis/content/test.js' type="text/javascript">


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Jquery Separate file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Thaalinda');
})
```

in here test.js located at (./content/test.js/)
before re-Writing it's working perfectly after that it's not working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute path in your url of ajax instead of relative path.
Change this
var link = "./content/php/updatequantity.php?quan="+value+"&id="+updateId;
to
var link = "/content/php/updatequantity.php?quan="+value+"&id="+updateId;

Comment: k ill try to do that